# RestSharp response forbidden

Tags: api, request, restsharp

I trying get a simple request to https://c-cex.com/t/prices.json

If i use this url in browser the correct response is showed , but if i make the same request using RestRequest i receive the 403 error Forbidden in all times. i trying  HttpClient,WebRequest i get the same error

I put the header with user-agent, no cache and a lot of another values but did not work

Any ideas about this problem?

```
Dim url As String = "https://c-cex.com/t/prices.json"
Dim client As New RestSharp.RestClient(url)
Dim request = New RestRequest(url, Method.GET)
Dim response = client.Execute(request)
```

Updated code with apisign request

```
Dim nonce As String = CInt((DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds).ToString

        Dim url As String = "https://c-cex.com/t/api.html?a=getbalance&currency=BTC&apikey=" & API_KEY & "&nonce=" & nonce


        Dim keybytes() = UnicodeEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(API_SECRET)
        Dim hs As System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512 = New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(keybytes)
        Dim urlbytes() = UnicodeEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url)

        Dim sh() = hs.ComputeHash(urlbytes)    

        Dim client As New RestSharp.RestClient(url)            

        Dim request = New RestRequest(url, Method.GET)
        request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        request.AddHeader("apisign", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ToHexString(sh)))    
        Dim response = client.Execute(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the response without providing the header information and It looks given piece of code is working correctly for me in VB and C#.As a best practice, base URL needs to be specified in RestClient and relative URL in RestRequest.

Please recheck without adding the request header information

**VB:**

```
  Imports RestSharp

Module Module1
    Sub Main()

        Dim host As String = "https://c-cex.com"
        Dim endpoit As String = "t/prices.json"
        Dim client As New RestSharp.RestClient(host)
        Dim request = New RestRequest(endpoit, Method.GET)
        Dim response = client.Execute(request)

        Console.WriteLine("Response Body " + response.Content)
        Console.WriteLine("Response Code " + response.StatusDescription)

    End Sub
End Module
```

**C#:**

```
    String host = "https://c-cex.com";
    String endpoint = "t/prices.json";

    RestClient _restClient = new RestClient(host);

    var request = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.GET);
    var response = _restClient.Execute(request);

    Console.WriteLine("Response Body :"+response.Content);
    Console.WriteLine("Response Status Code :" + response.StatusDescription);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for anwser Subburaj.I copy/paste your code and run and received the same error "StatusCode: Forbidden, Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: -1)". I d'ont know because i receive this error.

Comment: It looks, randomly forbidden error is coming while accessing the above URI(Captcha Authentication). I was able to get the responses successfully via POSTMAN, Browser and with the above script. But unfortunately,I am getting the Captcha Authentication error in browser and postman.. I have attached the  snapshot error from browser and Postman

Comment: Yes this is a problem! Readind the api documentation i can connect after click on "i'm not a robot" with the postman using a hashed api url, but in code i can't. I try use the cookie container of RestClient and nothing!

Comment: Yes, i have two postman one as chrome extension and one is a windows program. In the chrome not have an option to CODE, in windows app i received the same message than you to bypass "i'm not robot".

Comment: the generate code is 
var client = new RestClient("https://c-cex.com/t/api.html?a=getbalance&currency=BTC&apikey=we5F56Dasdasdasg
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "c24b304c-c794-402d-a01d-e3995671e87e");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("apisign", "88d7eba583b828b5asdasdasdasd4e2617eef51616070c8320b0653c0b9c4eab15de89201de0f");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Comment: i'm edit the code with hashed code. In postman i get the variable values like apisign, nonce etc and pass parameters in postman, if i bypass the verifcation i received a correct response 
{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Currency":"BTC","Balance":0.00000000,"Available":0,"Pending":0.00000000,"CryptoAddress":""}}